# Structuring program to handle data object from GUI object

Tags: python, oop, object, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm working on restructuring a data analysis GUI with PyQt5. I am trying to separate the inner workings/logic of the program from the GUI itself with a method similar to the Model/View approach. I will explain how I am thinking about structuring the program, but I'm not sure if this is best practice. I have separated the code into a main.py file that creates an data storing object, the custom class of which is defined in separate file of the project, and a main window object that constructs the GUI and is also defined in another file. Since the GUI loads the CSV into the data object by providing a filename chosen by the user, I have to have a way of calling the data object from the GUI. Should I pass the data object as an argument into the main window object?

My data storing class looks like this:

```
class DataHolder():

    def addCSV(self, loadedCSVPath):
        self.pt_df = pandas.read_csv(loadedCSVPath)
```

This is what the beginning of my GUI class would look like:

```
class ControlsWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, data_object, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Add a place to hold the data independent of the GUI
        self.data = data_object
        self.setLayouts()
```

There would also be a method later on for calling `self.data.addCSV('path/to/CSV')` to load the data to the data object, as well as some other methods for interacting and plotting the data. Overall, my main.py would look something like this:

```
def main():
    data = DataHolder()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    controls = ControlsWindow(data)
    controls.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does this method of separating the different operations of my program make sense? Is there a better way of interacting with the data object from the GUI object without passing the data object as an argument into the GUI class?

Comment: Your approach looks good to me. Just remember: in MVC the view knows about the model and can alter it, either directly or via the controller. The model does *not* know about the view(s). So if your model has changed it must advertise this via Qt Signals. As far as I can see you've got this covered.

Comment: @titusjan okay great, thank you! So if I am using the view to plot data from the model, but I only want to plot some of the data and I am using the model to select that data (the 'active' data), should I store the list containing the active data in the model or the view?

Comment: In general there can be multiple views looking at the same model, so the list of active data has to be stored in the view(s). Unless it's always the same for all views, in that case you could consider making it part of the model. Then the choice depends on what *active* means in your situation. Can you elaborate on that? Note that there is a third solution: using a [proxy model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#proxy-models) to store the active list. Qt's [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) can be used to filter only the active points.

Comment: @titusjan I have a csv with three columns: x, y, and slice. I am using the GUI to select certain values of slice so any rows in the csv with a matching value for slice will have the x & y values plotted. So in this case, the active data is essentially selected rows in the csv. Based on what you said, I think it makes sense for me to define the list of the active data in the view since that is where the values of slice are selected. I think this is a simple enough case that I don't need to use a proxy model, but thank you for bringing that to my attention!